# Linq-2-SQL Concat or Union Different types

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am trying to concatenate IQueryable where T can be different types.

So `((IQueryable<Person>)people).Concant((IQueryable<Account>)accounts).`

I have created a structure like so:

```
public struct PerformanceStructure
{
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
    public Entity Performance { get; set; }
}
```

I am building dynamic queries that follow this template:

```
    var result = context.Accounts.Where(a => a.id == 1).Select(s => new PerformanceStructure { Entity = s });
    result = result.Concat(context.Person.Where(p => p.id = 1).Select(s => new PerformanceStructure {Entity = s});
```

Execution looks like this:

```
var list = result.Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - )).Take(pageSize);
```

When executing the query, I get the error **Types in Union or Concat have different members assigned**

What can I do to resolve this error but retrieve the two objects from that database?

In the end I want to paginate the query (thus the skip/take) based on some order.

Comment: Have you tried taking results in to 2 different var and then concat or union. Like  result3 = result1.Union(result2).Then perform paging on result3. In this case result3 will be IQuarable and will not affect performance of paging.This may help you.

Comment: That is what the code is doing.  It is just reusing the result variable.